# Stream<double[]> vs DoubleStream

Tags: java-8, double, java-stream

I have to convert double value array into stream
    What is difference between following two approach? Which one is better ?

```
 double [] dArray = {1.2,2.3,3.4,4.5};
 Stream<double[]> usingStream =  Stream.of(dArray); //approach 1
 DoubleStream usingArrays = Arrays.stream(dArray); //approach 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `Stream.of(dArray)` gives you a `Stream<double[]>` whose single element is the input array, which is probably not what you want. You could use that approach if your input was a `Double[]` instead of a primitive array, since then you would have gotten a `Stream<Double>` of the elements of the array.

Therefore `Arrays.stream(dArray)` is the way to go when you need to transform an array of `double`s to a stream of `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that they are different?

`DoubleStream` can be thought as `Stream<Double>` (but as a primitive), while `Stream<double[]>` is a Stream of *array*s.

Answer (score 0):

`Stream.of` and `Arrays.stream` are entirely different things for different purposes and hence should not be compared.

`Stream.of` when passed a single dimensional array as in your example will yield a stream with a single element being the array itself which in majority of the cases is not what you want.

`Arrays.stream`, well as name suggests operates on *arrays*, whereas `Stream.of` is more general.

It would have been better and more entertaining had you asked what’s the difference between `DoubleStream.of(dArray)` and `Arrays.stream(dArray)`.

Comment: I think both (DoubleStream.of(dArray) and Arrays.stream(dArray)) are same thing as they returning DoubleStream. And Arrays.stream() having multiple overloaded methods to handle different type of arrays to convert them in respective type of stream..like IntStream, LongStream

Comment: @RajN well they’re “the same” in the sense that they both return a DoubleStream but they are different in the sense that one is designed to consume explicitly typed values (DoubleStream.of) and the other is intended to consume an array(Arrays.stream). But then one might say DoubleStream.of still produces the correct value given a double array. This is all due to varargs.. but ideally you _should_ use DoubleStream.of only when you want to pass explicit values e.g. DoubleStream.of(1.0,2.0,3.0) as it makes more sense and that’s its intended purpose.hence what makes this question more interesting.

Comment: @RajN Because the two are same in functionality but intended for different purposes I believe it makes this question a lot more interesting IMO.